# Can't get my head around the 8-N puzzle

Tags: algorithm

I have been reading [this](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~hzhang/c145/notes/03-probsolv.pdf)

If you go to slide 19, it will start talking about an 8-N puzzle.

1) So in order to solve this one has to generate all the possible states and then traverse the tree?

2) Ok if yes from 1), then why use a tree? Can I use another data structure?

3) Why do I need to generate all the states? Can't I just create them as I go, that will give me a chance to reach my goal faster no?

4) The start and goal states should be given right?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I like the use of the term tree in the beginning of the slides. I think you should consider it more like a graph, the actual data structure for implementation could be anything. 

The reason a graph is used is because there are well defined solutions to traversing / searching a graph (dijkstra, A*). So when you turn a problem into a graph, you can mathematically prove you can solve the problem in some bounded time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for solving 8-puzzle

1-3) You should generate all the possible states

reason:
You do not know the goal location.
There are many ways to reach the goal.
Some ways may fail to goal and need to backtracking.

2) Tree data structure

reason:
To avoid duplicate states.
In graph occurs duplicate states. It increases the time of search.

4) Start and goal
Only start state is specified.

Comment: In my recursion, what is the stopping condition ?

Comment: When the goal is reached.

Comment: hey can you have a look, at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810488/why-is-my-recursion-keep-throwing-a-stackoverflow-error I can't generate the state space

Comment: @TrtTrt I answer you question see my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to generate all the states in advance (you can generate them while you are moving along the states). You can also use a graph and mark the states you already tried (so not to try them later).

Yes, your starting position will be given to you (some random permutation of the elements). The end position is when the game is won. As far as I remember - for your puzzle it is an ordered position). For some other games you can have may positions (like in chess).

Comment: "while you are moving along the states", you mean while searching?

Comment: @TrtTrt yes. Assume that now you are in state1. You decided to move from it. You generated all the states reachable from state1 and selected where to move.