# Why is my recursion keep throwing a StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to generate a tree, of all the possible states of the 8-N [problem](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjqzYeisafNAhXLIsAKHSGCBuQQFggqMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstudhelp.net%2Forder%2Fdownloadfile%2F11557&usg=AFQjCNFd0g33SaS1y8G6N6NL6PYJo4xBdQ&sig2=QFQQ17MzKJrLCZf1klwB3A), with no duplicates. I can do it on paper but in code I can't.

Here is my recursive function:

```
......
...
..
        root = new TreeNode(startingState);
        visitedStates.add(root.getData().getStateValues());

        generateStateSpaceRecursive(root);
    }

public void generateStateSpaceRecursive(TreeNode node){

    List<TreeNode> nextStatesNodes = getNextStates(node);

    for (TreeNode childNode : nextStatesNodes){
        if(!stateVisited(childNode.getData().getStateValues())) {
            visitedStates.add(childNode.getData().getStateValues());
            node.addChild(childNode);
            generateStateSpaceRecursive(childNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Why would it not stop?

Also if I understood the problem correctly it says,

> Implement the following types of search to (try to)  solve this
>   problem: depth first, breadth first, iterative  deepening, some form
>   of heuristic search.

But I need the state space first right? Or I can just apply the algorithms and generate the states on the fly?

Edit:

```
private List<TreeNode> getNextStates(TreeNode node) {

        List<TreeNode> nextStates = new ArrayList<>();

        if(agent.canMoveLeft(node)){
            nextStates.add(agent.moveLeft(node));
        }
        if(agent.canMoveRight(node)){
            nextStates.add(agent.moveRight(node));
        }
        if(agent.canMoveUp(node)){
            nextStates.add(agent.moveUp(node));
        }
        if(agent.canMoveDown(node)){
            nextStates.add(agent.moveDown(node));
        }

        return nextStates;
    }
```

Comment: This is software; basically you can do whatever you want. In order to understand what is going on ... consider a) using the debugger b) writing unit tests. It is always a bad idea to "test"/"debug" "large" problems in one shot. Instead, you should focus on breaking up things as far as possible; test them individually ... and then when you are convinced that all operations involved work; then you throw them together.

Comment: @Jägermeister I am testing it individually. My recursion function in this case

Comment: show us your method getNextStates

Comment: @NicolasFilotto added in question, although I dont get how it can cause a problem

Comment: Self-correcting my prior comment: What makes you think you have to span up the complete State Space? As far as I understood the Task description, you are supposed to implement the different search methods (spanning the tree "on the fly") and see which of them can solve the task and what the performance benefits or drawbacks are between them. Your code is like you try to compute every possible move (transition between two unique states) which is excessive in space and time.

Comment: @Fildor well the idea (my idea lol) was to generate everything and then apply the search algorithms.. I guess that was wrong. but if I do apply the search algorithms  that means I will have to generate things on the fly... Either way is correct right?

Comment: Either way would be correct. Spanning the whole possible space is just in most cases impossible. Think of a chess computer. Or a Navigation-software ... They would need vast amounts of memory.

Comment: But in my case I would have a 16! number of states. That isn't a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is too big to fit the stack. Test your algorithm:

- with a smaller sample.
- or increase your stack size (e.g. java -Xss4m)

Comment: hey! this might be! but how did you come up to this conclusion?

Comment: Because you seemed very sure that your algorithm is correct i.e. does not contain "infinite recursion" ;-) "I can do it on paper but in code I can't."

Comment: It worked! Thanks, now my tree seems to be the problem, I keep getting a tree in which every child node has one node only

Comment: Glad it worked! Your second issue seems to be another issue / question. The "recursion throwing a StackOverflow error" is solved, right? Please 'accept' the correct answer and post another question to keep the topic about the stack overflow "clean".

Comment: Probably because your 'agents' can only head a single direction (left, right, up or down)? You might want to attach a debugger to the process and step through the algorithm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114644/discussion-between-trt-trt-and-niels).

Answer (score 1):

You should edit generateStateSpaceRecursive:

```
public void generateStateSpaceRecursive(TreeNode node)
{    
 if(!testGoal)
  {
    //Goal node is not seen
    List<TreeNode> nextStatesNodes = getNextStates(node);    
    ...
  }
 else 
   //Goal Node Visited    
}
```

Create new function like this:

```
private bool testGoal(TreeNode node)
{
  if(node == goalNode) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do I need an else ?